# How to fix a Parse Error in Pandas read csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas

how to fix this python error (pandas lib).
why does it happen? please help

```
import pandas as pd
url='https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-23-2020.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url) 
data.describe()
```

> ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import pandas as pd
>         2 url='https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-23-2020.csv'
>   ----> 3 data = pd.read_csv(url)
>         4 data.describe()
>
> 3 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py
>   in read(self, nrows)    2057     def read(self, nrows=None):    2058
>   try:
>   -> 2059             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    2060         except StopIteration:    2061             if self._first_chunk:

Comment: You should choose 'view raw' and copy that link

Answer (score 0):

You may try this adress

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-23-2020.csv"
```